# Programación en Python, impresión de serie numérica varias veces

Tags: python, python-3.x

Deseo imprimir una serie de 10 números 10 veces, hasta ahora solo he logrado esto, lo que quiero hacer es imprimir limpiamente así:

> 12345678910 12345678910 12345678910...etc. diez veces)

Actualmente me sale así:

> **1** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 **2** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 **3** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 **4** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 **5** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 **6** 1 2 3...

El código que hice es el siguiente:

```
for serie_A in range(1, 11):

    cont = 0
    print(serie_A, end=' ')
    for serie_B in range(1, 11):
        print(serie_B, end=' ')
        cont = cont + 1
        if cont > 10:
            break
```

Comment: No hay duda de que deseas imprimir una serie númerica. Pero, ¿cuál es la pregunta? ¿Qué está mal con el código? Necesitamos más información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Además el código imprime el número de iteración mas 10 números 10 veces, por lo que parece que responde a tu propia pregunta. Por favor edita tu pregunta y aclara lo que deseas hacer y el problema.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estas recibiendo es que cada vez que imprimes el numero esta generando un espacio y lo que quieres es que genere la serie sin espacios y después cree un espacio, para esto puedes crear un bucle que genere la serie '12345678910' y después cree el espacio.

También te recomiendo modificar el:

```
if cont > 10:
break
```

y simplemente crear un bucle while que continué mientras el contador sea menor que 10 dejo el código que soluciona este problema, te recomiendo encarecidamente que experimentes con este código para ver exactamente que hace cada parte:

```
def series(num_series: int) -> str:
    # Creo una funcion que cumple tu proposito
    cont = 0

    while cont < num_series:
        for serie in range(1, 11):
            print(serie, end='')
            # Imprimo la serie 12345678910

        print(' ', end='')
        # Imprimo el espacio para separar las series

        cont += 1
        # Sumo uno al contador


series(10)
```

Espero que esto responda tu pregunta.

**Nota:** El `cont += 1` lo que realiza es lo mismo que el `cont = cont + 1` pero de forma abreviada.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes el código correcto para lo que tú querías:

```
for serie_A in range(1, 11):

    cont = 0
    for serie_B in range(1, 11):
        print(serie_B, end='')
        cont = cont + 1
        if cont > 10:
            break
    print("", end = " ")
```

Los errores en tu código estaban en añadir `end = " "` (con un espacio) en la línea de `print(serie_B, end='')`, esto hacía que los números se separaran siempre.

Luego, era innecesario imprimir por pantalla serie_A (`print(serie_A, end=' ')`), el bucle de serie_A solamente se utiliza para separar los bloques de números, no es necesario imprimir su valor. Además, esta línea debe estar después del bucle de serie_B, para que no añada un espacio al principio del string.

Espero que se haya entendido.